# Ajax post with data from jquery .text()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem, the solution might be very simple but I just can't find it for a couple of hours already. Basically I have an Ajax post to a controller. I want the data sent with Ajax to be taken from a  with class ".theme-h1" from my page, so I have this

```
function get_video_reviews_data(){
something = $(".theme-h1").text();
alert(something);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/video_reviews_data",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { title: something },
})
.done(function(data) {
    alert(data.title);
    get_video_reviews_videos(data);
}); }
```

In this situation, my controller does not see $_POST['title'] for some reason. 
If I change the second line to this:

```
something = "some text";
```

then I can see $_POST['title'] in my controller.
I also tried changing this:

```
data: { title: something },
```

to this:

```
data: { title: $(".theme-h1").text() },
```

and it still doesn't work. Seems like I can only have a value between quotes for the variable I'm sending.

Please help me out :)
Thank you!

Comment: Let us see your HTML please :)

Comment: what is `.theme-h1` reffering to ?

Comment: This is the div in my view:
<h1 class="theme-h1">
<?php
echo $product->ItemAttributes->Title;
?>
</h1>

It is just a title of the product

Comment: This really bugs me, doesn't .text() already return a string? Why is it not picked up by the Ajax call and why does it work when I just write `data: { title : "text" } ` for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encasing your value in parenthesis:

```
function get_video_reviews_data(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/video_reviews_data",
        data: {
            title:($(".theme-h1").text())
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data.title);
        get_video_reviews_videos(data);
    }); 
}
```

Not sure why, but I found by encasing it in parenthesis it magically will allow for calling jQuery methods when it wouldn't before.

Also, notice I got rid of `datatype:'json'`. Don't leave that up to intelligent guessing (which is really what jQuery does, it is far from bulletproof), explicitly declare it in the header for the file:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Which **is** bulletproof. I also noticed you had a trailing comma after the `data` object, so I removed that as well.

Comment: Tried it, still nothing, can't see the variable in the controller.
This is my controller: 

`public function video_reviews_data(){
$search_term = $_POST['title'];
$data['title'] = $_POST['title'];
}
echo json_encode($data); 
`

Comment: Your method worked for some reason :) I did have to add the datatype back though since the response from the controller is json_encoded.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please check on console that $(".theme-h1").text() returns something as a string.

Comment: It does return the text of the title like this
http://s23.postimg.org/pfnanp77f/Capture.png"

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Please remove the additional comma after $data in the answer below and try again...

also, do you use firebug to debug your code in the browser?  If so, what does your "Post" information show?

Try this:

```
something = $(".theme-h1").text();

$data = "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(something);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/video_reviews_data",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $data,  
})
.done(function(data) {
    alert(data.title);
    get_video_reviews_videos(data);
}); }
```

Comment: Tried, same thing, $_POST['title'] is empty.